# Poem that ends with "...whispers, snow!"

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I recall a poem that talks about nature and the changing seasons (maybe Summer to Autumn, or Autumn to Winter) that ends with **"...whispers, snow!"**

I've Googled the phrase with and without punctuation and have read more poems about Autumn (that are also apparently metaphors about death) so before I sink even further into a black gloom, can anyone provide the poem and poet where this phrase appears?

Comment: If this seems right I’ll make it an answer.  https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=izQUBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT154&lpg=PT154&dq=%22whispers+snow%22+poem&source=bl&ots=4tWff40Miw&sig=ulnvaSKauNXJaJFHPQi4uPSRG-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyyd7I8bTXAhUFfRoKHVDtAxQQ6AEIXDAQ#v=onepage&q=%22whispers%20snow%22%20poem&f=false

Comment: Thanks @Spagirl - though a lovely poem, it's not the one.  I really appreciate your suggestion though! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started looking into this because I thought that I recognised the quote, but it rapidly led me to the same saturation of Autumn poems described above.

I finally found a variation on the phrase in the poem:

> "Something told the wild geese", by Rachel Field.

Here is an excerpt from the poem:

> 'Something told the wild geese
>   
> It was time to go,
>   
> Though the fields lay golden
>   
> Something whispered, "snow."... '

[Here's](http://www.yourdailypoem.com/listpoem.jsp?poem_id=522) a link to this poem in case it's the one you were looking for.